# Node 'magically' changes

Tags: 6, nodes, i18n-l10n

I manage a drupal 6.x site for someone, sometimes some weird content is posted which is a mixture between Dutch, English and vague words. E.g:

> Ik ARE-op zoek WHAT

We delete these kinds of messages and contact the owner of the post, as they're not really spam but just ... weird messages. This happened a couple of times now.

According to the owners, they have not posted the message in that way (which I highly doubt). So my question is; has anyone ever ever heard of Drupal changing messages that way? Perhaps through some kind of translating feature?

Comment: No, Drupal won't do that unless it's configured to do that.

Comment: I had similar issue. Turning on revisioning helped - we was able to find which one of the editors logs in from insecure terminals and fails to log out... @Clive do you know any example of Drupal module that can do this on it's own when misconfigured?

Comment: @Mołot Anything that defines a filter format could be responsible really...or any preprocess/content build hook. It's hard to speculate

Comment: Thanks about that revision stuff, good idea. I have enabled it. And we'll see. The only filters I know of is the HTML filters that are applied, I don't think it'll change the node so rigorously it'll mix up English and Dutch and capitalize entire words.